# SOS-Berlin JobScheduler - Database User Authentication

Tags: mysql, job-scheduling

I am trying to implement SOS-Berlin JobScheduler with User Authentication using MySQL but  it is throwing error shown below :
the url  http://127.0.0.1:40444 is working well.
[image: error image-1]

[image: error image -2]

[image: DB schema]

[image: DB]

[image: DB]

please suggest me the way to do this....

Comment: can someone with 1500+ add the SOS-Berlin tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What code are you using to connect to MySQL with?

See: https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/How+to+operate+JobScheduler+with+Jetty

Otherwise you will need to contact SOS-Berlin about Database Driven User Authentication.